# Amazon Connect CTI Flows Dereference Variables

Tags: opencti, amazon-connect

Specific Question for the [Amazon Connect CTI Managed Package](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EJH4yUAH) (Specifically V5+ which introduces `CTI Flows`)

I am looking for an example of how to *dereference* a variable collected in a previous `CTI Block`, in a `runApex` (Which is [OpenCTI `runApex` method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_runapex_lex.htm)):

The example given for parameters is:

```
name=acme&phone=(212) 555-5555
```

But I would like to say run a "Get Contact Attribute" in a CTI Block, and then pass the result to the APEX Method:

```
name=$.action.uid-12.results.value
```

I would also like to be able to locate the current users' ProfileId or UserId.

Comment: Hi @jordan.baucke did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround. You can use **Join Strings** CTI block to join 2 string and then you can use the result of this block.

So lets say you are using Join Strings CTI block UID-10:
1 operand  will be **name=**
2 operand will be **$.action.uid-12.results.value.**
The result of this block will be name=value

And then in your Run Apex CTI block in methodParams you can use the value from your join Strings CTI block UID-10.

I hope this will help you.